Why is my Haproxy health check (Ping-pong) not working on my redis server?
I started a new server and installed Redis on it.
    sudo apt-get install lsb-release curl gpg
    curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
    sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install redis -y
    sudo apt-get install redis-tools -y

Modified /etc/redis/redis.conf to change the bind to:
bind 0.0.0.0 -::1
Restarted the server, and installed HAProxy 2.8 in another VPS.  Modified the HAProxy config the same as the following article, changing the IPs (frontend IP being the HAproxy server IP, and backend server IP being the Redis server IP) and removing the .
https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/deploying-highly-available-redis-replication-with-haproxy-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure
I am getting the
Health check for server redis_cluster/redis1 failed, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK did not match content '+PONG' at step 3", check duration: 1ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.

First question, since default mode is TCP, why is the failure Layer7?
Second question, the Redis does not have a requirepass, so no authentication is needed.  There is no firewall.  So there is no networking issue.  Why did my check on Ping-pong response fail?
The reason why I am testing Haproxy-Redis connection is I am also getting the same error with a 3 server Redis Sentinel setup that I want to do failover via HAProxy, so I am doing a test with a simple 1 server backend in HAProxy to try to figure out what's going on.
